# Adding touch targets over a PDF document in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm looking to add a degree of interactivity to a set of PDF files that I have, and would like to embed a PDF document in a webpage, and then overlay touch targets to I can make a popop over them.

What would be the best way to make this happen? I briefly looked into Mozilla's [pdf.js](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/), but thats more focused on being a full on PDF reader, and has sluggish performance on tablets.

Are there any reliable PDF to HTML libraries/converters that could help me out? The PDF's are fairly basic. More or less just a bunch of images (which are individually selectable in the PDF) in a grid.

At the moment I am opening the PDF in Photoshop, slicing it up, and then exporting it as an HTML table, but I would love something a bit easier to do

Comment: What is your backend language? PHP? Java? Ruby?

Comment: Ideally, I would like this to happen client-side, but I'm willing to compromise if I have to for a server-side solution.

Comment: The browser needs a plugin for displaying PDF-files. You can't lay anything over the plugin. You could try to load it in an iframe (if the user has such a plugin), but you can't recognize scrolling then.

Comment: Incidentally, this may be possible natively: http://indesignsecrets.com/showing-and-hiding-objects-in-interactive-pdf.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see a way around a server-side solution. Here is how I would do it in PHP using ImageMagick:

```
<?php
$someFile = $_GET['pdf'];
try
{
    // Saving every page of a PDF separately as a JPG thumbnail
    $images = new Imagick($someFile);
    foreach($images as $i=>$image) {
        $desiredWidth = 1024;
        $image->thumbnailImage($desiredWidth,0);
        // Save the file to disk
        //$image->writeImage("page".$i.".jpg");
        // Or display it from this script:
        header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
        echo $image;
    }
    $images->clear();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

If your PDF is a single page then that script will just create a single file or if you echo the $image then it will just display that page as a JPG (or PNG or whatever you want). Then you can mark up your HTML around it as needed by including the script as an IMG:

```
<img src="myscript.php?pdf=somefile.pdf"/>
```

Now you can have whatever HTML you want over and around the PDF as an image.

Comment: Ok, this is very helpful. This, for my purpose, is 'clientside' enough

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a commercial solution called PDFWebViewer.NET to view PDFs in the browser a couple of years ago. It uses server side image rendering (.NET) and nothing but HTML and javascript client side.

I think that's as close as you can get to viewing PDF in the browser without any plugins. Since it's all HTML you can overlay pages with divs and hook up actions to that using javascript. In fact, that's how the product renders out links in the PDF documents.

This works really well because by using relative positioning you can make sure the links stay in the right place while panning the document.

The project was recently open sourced but still relies on commercial components. It should not be a lot of work to replace that with open source PDF components.

The project is hosted on codeplex. [PDFWebViewer 1](http://pdfwebviewer1.codeplex.com/) is the first generation, [WebViewer 2](http://webviewer2.codeplex.com/) is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). It allow you to work bassically with any web content whitch is on the fly converted to pdf format by taking a "snapshot of screen" (simple explanation). For example you can write your own html template just like you would on any website and than populate it with custom data. You can use it generate for example an invoice. Im using it for couple months now and without any single problem.

Its simple shell utility to convert html to pdf using the webkit rendering engine, and qt. And of cource its open source!

Example:

```
wkhtmltopdf www.myhomepage.com myhomepage.pdf
```